# How to assign categories to columns in R so that values within those categories can be summed for each row?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame in R which is organized with sampled trees in rows and different lichen species in columns. Count data for each lichen species per tree is listed in each column.

| Tree_ID | Lichen_A | Lichen_B | Lichen_C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tree1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| Tree2 | 2 | 5 | 7 |

I would like to categorize the lichens and count the number seen per tree according to category. Ideally, the categories could be imported from another data frame which could look like this. Certain lichens will share the same category.

| Lichen | Sensitivity |
| --- | --- |
| Lichen_A | Low |
| Lichen_B | Low |
| Lichen_C | Medium |

Combining these to get the sum of the categories would look like this:

| Tree_ID | Low | Medium |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tree1 | 3 | 3 |
| Tree2 | 7 | 7 |

In reality I have about 40 different lichen species, two sensitivity categories and multiple datasets of trees, so I'd like to find a solution that means I don't need to do everything manually.

I am not sure how to set up the code for this, though I have a feeling it should be possible, perhaps with a loop and/or dplyr mutate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(unique(df2$Lichen)) %>% 
  inner_join(df2, by = c("name" = "Lichen")) %>% 
  group_by(Tree_ID, Sensitivity) %>% 
  summarise(value = sum(value)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Sensitivity")

  Tree_ID   Low Medium
1 Tree1       3      3
2 Tree2       7      7
```

---

data

```r
df1 <- read.table(header = T,text = "Tree_ID    Lichen_A    Lichen_B    Lichen_C
Tree1   1   2   3
Tree2   2   5   7")


df2 <- read.table(header = T,text= "
Lichen  Sensitivity
Lichen_A    Low
Lichen_B    Low
Lichen_C    Medium")
```

Comment: I'm getting the error `Error in "pivot_longer()":
! Can't combine "Year" <double> and "Tree_species" <character>.` This is referring to some of the other columns in the original data set. Each tree has a year for survey date and the species of the tree, among other things.

Comment: Do I need to change the column classes?

Comment: check edit, use `starts_with("Lichen")`

Comment: Does this mean the columns need to contain the word "Lichen"? The real column names are different, the ones above are just a simplified example.

Comment: Yes it means that. Do whatever you can to select them. You can check this page for helping functions: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_tidy_select.html

Comment: Is there a way to select them based on a word match with the second dataset? Since it may be difficult otherwise, they are 40 unique names.

Comment: you could use `unique(df2$Lichen)`

Comment: I got it to work with `pivot_longer(c(9:45))` to capture the columns. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

With little effort you can `sapply` over the `unique` Sensitivities to subset `dat` and get the `rowSums` that we `cbind` to first column.

```
cbind(dat[1], sapply(unique(ctgr$Sensitivity), \(x) {
  rowSums(dat[names(dat) %in% ctgr$Lichen[ctgr$Sensitivity == x]])
}))
#   Tree_ID Low Medium
# 1   Tree1   3      3
# 2   Tree2   7      7
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(Tree_ID = c("Tree1", "Tree2"), Lichen_A = 1:2, 
    Lichen_B = c(2L, 5L), Lichen_C = c(3L, 7L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))

ctgr <- read.table(text='Lichen     Sensitivity
Lichen_A    Low
Lichen_B    Low
Lichen_C    Medium', header=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(df1), id.var = "Tree_ID", variable.name = "Lichen")[df2, 
 on = .(Lichen)], Tree_ID ~ Sensitivity, value.var = "value", sum)
```

-output

```
   Tree_ID Low Medium
1:   Tree1   3      3
2:   Tree2   7      7
```